# imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not getting called on Image Selection

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

In my class below, `imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject])` is not getting called, and I don't understand why. This is a class that extends [`JSQMessagesViewController`](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController), dont know if that's got to do with it.

The `UIImagePickerController` does not get added from the Storyboard. I am guessing it is added when extending `JSQMessagesViewController`?(Can't tell)

Anyhow, I can see that the function `actionSheet` does bring up the imagePicker Photo album and I can select an image but the imagePicker function `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` never gets called.

How do I assign this class to be its delegate?

[**Here is the complete class code**](https://github.com/huyouare/SwiftParseChat/blob/c8d96bf865174b0761f4128101a45948da16a5fd/SwiftParseChat/ChatViewController.swift) (this example on GitHub is working, but I am not able to get it working in my project, what am I missing?)

```
class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

}

    //DELETED THE REST OF THE CODE OF THIS CLASS TO KEEP THIS QUESTION LENGTH SHORT

func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

    NSLog("ChatViewController-> actionSheet(clickedButtonAtIndex)")
    if buttonIndex != actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex {
        if buttonIndex == 1 {
            Camera.shouldStartCamera(self, canEdit: true, frontFacing: true)
        } else if buttonIndex == 2 {
            Camera.shouldStartPhotoLibrary(self, canEdit: true)
        } else if buttonIndex == 3 {
            Camera.shouldStartVideoLibrary(self, canEdit: true)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate



func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    //THIS FUNCTION NEVER GETS CALLED AFTER AN IMAGE IS SELECTED FROM THE PHOTO ALBUM

}



}
```

Comment: "this example on GitHub is working, but I am not able to get it working in my project, what am I missing" Who knows? You need to post an example that _isn't_ working if you want use to be able to think about why it isn't working. :)

Comment: It looks like the `Camera.shouldStartPhotoLibrary` method is probably presenting the `UIImagePickerController`. Where is that method defined?

Comment: @ganzogo You are right there was a delegate=self line in `Camera.shouldStartPhotoLibrary` that was commented out. Just add that as an answer, I will mark it. I should have been more thorough in reviewing the code.

Comment: @user1406716 okay have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Camera.shouldStartPhotoLibrary` method is probably presenting the `UIImagePickerController`. Check where that is defined.